# Wrong time scaling in Grafana

Tags: time, timezone, visualization, grafana, influxdb

I have a problem with the visualization in Grafana.
My problem is that dates are shifted one hour into the future.

[Grafana visualisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hyp4.png)

At the time of the screenshot it was 19:45. The data was recorded between 18:53 and 19:02 and also correctly noted in the database (InfluxDB). But are displayed from 19:53 to 20:02 in Grafana (as also seen on the picture above).

[DBeaver database data overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbwm7.png)

I have already checked the Grafana Server's time as well as the InfluxDB installation time and they match the current time.
My time zone is 'Europe/Berlin' (CET). I think this problem has something to do with time zones, but can't come up with the solution.  I would appreciate an answer very much.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. Data in the InfluxDB are saved in the UTC timezone, e.g. `2022-01-04 18:53:00 UTC`. But Grafana (dashboard) is located in CET timezone, so UTC time is showed in the CET timezone - `2022-01-04 18:53:00 UTC` = `2022-01-04 19:53:00 CET`. That's a default Grafana behaviour. You can customize it in the [Grafana dashboard time setting](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/time-range-controls/#dashboard-time-settings). So you may set `UTC` timezone for the dashboard, if your want to see date in the same timezone as you have saved in the InfluxDB.